# How to get rid of that blank page in Crystal report?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

In My .rpt file I have selected "format with multiple columns" option and Edited in "Layout" tab with following setting.

my print direction is "Down then across"
Width:2.500
Horizontal:1.000
vertical: 0.230

with the above settings I am getting  a blank page at the End How to get rid of that blank page?

Comment: Which section is being displayed?  You will see the name in the gutter on the last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,I found the answer I have a report footer which is no use that I deleted .

Answer (score 1):

Just Suppress `Report Footer` all will be ok

Answer (score 0):

To remove this blank page, you can add a formula for the New Page After option instead of simply checking it.  Click on the formula button and add the following:

Not OnLastRecord

Save and Close and you’re done.  Now everything except the very last group will get a new page after it.

Comment: Do your blank page have any sort of data like footer/header.

Comment: Yes,I found the answer I have a report footer which is no use that I deleted .

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove the blank pages other than to determine why they are occurring and fix the problem.

A blank last page is normally caused by having `NEW PAGE AFTER` selected for a section like the `DETAILS` or a `enter code here`

CR 8 instructions.
Open the report
Click `FORMAT` --> `SECTION`
Select the details section
If `NEW PAGE AFTER` is checked , uncheck it and click the `FORMULA BUTTON` to the right
Enter the formula
Not OnLastRecord

If there are groups check each group footer (it will probably be the Group #1 footer)
If `NEW PAGE AFTER` is checked , uncheck it and click the `FORMULA BUTTON` to the right
Enter the formula

```
Not OnLastRecord
```

If the balnk pages are through out the report you may have `NEW PAGE AFTER` or `NEW PAGE BEFORE` selected so both are producing a pnew page.
For instance if you hae `NEW PAGE AFTER`  on the group footer and `NEW PAGE BEFORE`on the group header.

Another cause of blank pages in the report is a field is too wide to fit on the page then you get a page printing to fnish the right hand end of the field which may be blank.  Make sure the entire field fits on the page

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a delayed response.

Think others will find this useful.

Open the report in crystal report designer.

Some of the control/controls in the report might have exceeded the report area

Please right click on the blank report area and choose page setup.

try setting the **left top right bottom** margins to a much lower value. Usually, I put the value to **0.00 MM** and check if this solves the issue.

If this removes the blank page, try finding the margin that is the real cause, by entering the margin values one by one.

If there is **blank page** after each page. This probably will be your solution.

The same issue will cause adding **blank space** on top of the report page after page, if 'keep together' option is not ticked in 'Section expert' for 'details'.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my report:

I unchecked the "Print at Bottom of Page" option in each section.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I open the `section Expert` dialog box and select the blank page from `sections` tab and then click on the `delete` button in top of the dialog box. This removed my blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and what was causing it was one of my images was extended off the page. Once I cropped the blank edge off it fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

for removing the first blank page in crystal report , follow the link

right click on Group section -->go to Change group --> then Uncheck the keep Group together